# Playground using with Objective-C iOS8

Tags: ios

I have just started working in iOS8. I have seen here Playground concept. But I didn't understand it. I have read that it could be only used with the Swift language.
I have referred documents from [this link](http://www.imore.com/ios-8,%20http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/ios-8-interactive-playgrounds/) .

Can we use it with Objective-C too?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What in the tapdancing world does the title have to do with this question?

Comment: Extremely sorry i have mistaken.

Comment: For a non-native English speaker, this question has a relevant title. Please give some slack.

Answer (score 4):

The playground concept is built upon a technology called REPL ([More info on REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop))

Basically you can type code into the playground which is 'compiled' (evaluated) on the fly so you can see the output/result.

It's quite a nice way to play with a language, design a function or test an algorithm, but you cannot build a distributable app with a playground.

For a playground concept to work a given language needs to support REPL. Currently Objective C does not support this, therefore only Swift is available in playground form.

Comment: @TanviJain My pleasure! - Feel free to accept the answer if you're satisfied :)